# Sequelize: how to show value of db.sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIME')

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

So I have a weird problem on a query comparing with the current time. Maybe a timezone probleme, but to be sure, I tried to check what it really compare by doing :

```
const data = await db.Bar.findAll({
            where: {
[Op.and]: [
               {
                    [dayAttributeOpening]:
                    {
                         [Op.lte]: db.sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIME')  // here
                    }
                },
//........
```

So I made the following code to check :

```
const time = await db.Bar.sequelize.query("Select now()")
console.log("Time now: " + JSON.stringify(time, null, 4));
const time2 = db.sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIME')
console.log("Time now literal: " + JSON.stringify(time2, null, 4))
```

and gives the folowing output:

> ```
> Time now: [
>     {
>         "now": "2023-12-06T01:41:11.375Z"
>     }
> ,...
> Time now literal: {
>     "val": "CURRENT_TIME"
> }
> ```

`Select now()` should have given `2023-12-06T02:41:11.375Z`

How can I write it properly to console.log the `db.sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIME')`? And would it be the same than now() on the server ?

Answer (score 0):

CURRENT_TIME is a constant on postgres, so:

```
 const time = await db.Bar.sequelize.query("Select CURRENT_TIME")
 console.log("CURRENT_TIME: ", time);
```

gives :

> CURRENT_TIME:  [   [ { current_time: '15:00:45.709239+02' } ],...